# Is it possible to create a Google Chrome extension that can set my computer's network settings?

Tags: google-chrome, networking, browser, google-chrome-extension, settings

I have a device that uses Chrome browser for it's front end.
I would like to add a wizard to it, but I don't want to use up any more memory or storage space on the device, especially since the wizard will likely only be used once, during the initial device setup.

So, it is possible to create a Google Chrome extension that can access and change my computer's network settings, as long as I give it permission to do so, or is that completely out of scope for a Google Chrome extension?

Basically, I want the extension to walk the customer through the initial setup process, part of which includes configuring the computer's network settings to be compatible with the device's default network settings. At the end of the wizard, the extension would put the computer's network settings back to what they originally were.

Comment: Nope. You can write a native OS utility to do that, and your extension can communicate with it via nativeMessaging API.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to create a Google Chrome extension that can access and change my computer's network settings, as long as I give it permission to do so [...]

No, no Chrome API provides this level of access. So an extension cannot do it *on its own.*

As wOxxOm mentions in a comment, it's possible to also [provide a separate program (called Native Host) that an extension can start, then talk to it](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) to do things outside of extension APIs. However, that complicates the deployment of such an extension: you can't add the host components to a Web Store app, you need a separate installer for it.

Presumably, you're targeting multiple OSes with the browser being an interface for your device; this further complicates your hypothetical "wizard" and its installer.

Perhaps the best you can do is clear documentation + an extension/webpage that can test  connectivity and suggest troubleshooting steps.

Comment: Thanks. I was 99% sure that this was not possible, but I thought I'd ask the experts to confirm.

Answer (score -1):

Your requirement is not still clear.
But it is understood that you want to change the ip address settings through any app.which will store a basic setting saved.
it is possible for some specific area but I don't know what is your condition.